# Values are not stored in array AsyncStorage react native

Tags: arrays, react-native, asyncstorage

I am trying to store values in AsyncStorage as array, but values are not saving there and getting nothing when i try to get the values from array.Any help would be appreciated.Thank you in advance,here is my code :

```
let searchString = this.state.inputValue

AsyncStorage.getItem('searches', (res) => {
  var searches
  if (res === null) {
    searches = []
  }else {
    searches = JSON.parse(res)
  }
  searches.push({
      searchString: searchString
  })
  AsyncStorage.setItem('searches', JSON.stringify(searches), (res) => {
      console.log('====FirstPage====setItem==async==='+res)
  })
});
```

//getting values from asyncstorage :

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('searches', (res) => {console.log('===res==='+res)})
```

Comment: Could you show the code for saving/storing values in AsyncStorage ?

Comment: Did you use AsyncStorage.getItem() ?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("searches").then((value) => {
    this.setState({"searches": value});
}).done();
```

Also see
https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/09/saving-data-in-your-react-native-mobile-application/

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data as following:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('searches', JSON.stringify(searchString));
```

In order to fetch/get, you can do that using following:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('searches', (err, result) => { // err indicating the error
  console.log("Storage Data(String):", result); // print is string format
  console.log("Storage Data(Object):", JSON.parse(result)); // print is json format
})
```

Comment: input value is saving in asyncstorage now but on second input it overrides the first value not appending the value like an array.

Comment: You mean u are doing AsyncStorage.setItem for 'searches' multiple times ?